# How can I use values given by result.fit_report()?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I've done the fit of a double Guassian function using the Lmfit library.

```
gmodel = Model(myDGauss)
result = gmodel.fit(yGauss, x=xGauss, I1=2.47,I2=2.63,sigma1=1.07,sigma2=1.15)
```

I've printed the fit report using the method fit_report():

```
print(result.fit_report())
```

and I've got what shown below:

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 76
    # data points      = 130
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 0.00559033
    reduced chi-square = 4.4368e-05
    Akaike info crit   = -1299.05274
    Bayesian info crit = -1287.58260 [[Variables]]
[[Variables]]
    I1:      0.74813688 +/- 0.01143576 (1.53%) (init = 2.475306)
    I2:      0.23722309 +/- 0.01099214 (4.63%) (init = 2.638552)
    sigma1:  1.23574890 +/- 0.00724975 (0.59%) (init = 1.070258)
    sigma2:  0.57214098 +/- 0.01513481 (2.65%) (init = 1.157566)
```

What I'd like to do now is to save the values of the fit_report printed in some variables. For example, I'd like to put the value of `I1` printed (0.74813688) in the variable `valI1`, that is a variable inizialized to 0.

Could anyone help me, please? Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you paste expected output?

Comment: Sure, I've edit the script. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the values printed in `ModelResult.fit_report()` are attributes of the `result` variable, which is a `ModelResult` instance. This has a number of attributes and methods, described at https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#the-modelresult-class

For example, the best-fit parameters are held in `result.params`.  As described at
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html,  this is an ordered dictionary with keys being the names of the individual parameters and the value being the Parameter object itself (see https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html#the-parameter-class) that has many attributes.

So to print the best-fit value and standard error for the Parameters, similar to what `fit_report()` does, you could do something like this:

```
for name, par in result.params.items():
     print("  %s: value=%f +/- %f " % (name, par.value, par.stderr))
```

More simply, and more directly what you ask for, would be:

```
valI1 = result.params['I1'].value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's what I was looking for!